# Case Statements In Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, case

Im trying to create a Case statement to determine if an attribute is present, if it is then show a link for example.

```
<% case %>
<% when @team_member.twitter? %>
  <%= link_to '', @team_member.twitter, target: '_blank', class: 'icon-twitter' %
<% when @team_member.facebook? %>
  <%= link_to '', @team_member.facebook, target: '_blank', class: 'icon-facebook' %>
<% end %>
```

Obviously this isnt working, what i wanted to clarify is

1) What do i declare after the initial case, examples i have seen have something like `<% case a %>` or `<% case object %>`, is that correct?
2) how do i check that an object has an attribute?

So what im looking to do here is say when `:team_member` has its twitter attribute populated then show the link, the same for the facebook attribute.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Either `<% case %>` or `<% case thingy %>` should work. You just can't mix them. So if you have `thingy`, then the `when` expressions must represent values of `thingy`. Otherwise, without `thingy` they are stand-alone expressions. The first one that has a true value will be executed and the `case` terminates. Why do you think your current `case` isn't working?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603321/rails-switch-case-in-the-view

Comment: Should this not be `if` rather than `case`?  Case statements are for varying behaviour based on different values of an attribute - but you want behavious based on two different attributes.  What happens if a team member has both twitter and facebook accounts?

Comment: apologies, i thought it was clear that when both attributes are present then show both links to facebook and twitter

Comment: Lots of answers here guys, thank you all for clarifying my understanding of when to use case statements and regular if statements

Comment: Ruby case is not like php switch for example, which would fall through  all matching cases.

Comment: @GraemeMcLean It turned out you were right. But it became evident only after the OP commented so. I only react depending on what has been made clear by the OP.

Comment: FYI, the Ruby `case` statement does *not* require a target expression to evaluate at the head of the case. See, for example, http://ruby.about.com/od/control/a/The-Case-Statement.htm. As long as it's used consistently throughout the `case` statement, it can work with no expression in the head, and independent evaluable expressions in the `when` clauses.

Answer (score 5):

1. <strike>That's right, `case` needs a target expression to evaluate.</strike> Edit: @mbratch pointed out in the comments that `case` can work without a target expression, as mentioned [here](http://ruby.about.com/od/control/a/The-Case-Statement.htm). This makes `case` work like an `if/else` construct.
2. If your object is an `ActiveRecord` model, you can use `has_attribute?(attr_name)`

In your code it is probably easier to use `if` statements, since you probably want to display both a twitter and facebook link if the user has those attributes set.

```
<% if @team_member.has_attribute?(:twitter) %>
  <%= link_to '', @team_member.twitter, target: '_blank', class: 'icon-twitter' %>
<% end %>
<% if @team_member.has_attribute?(:facebook) %>
  <%= link_to '', @team_member.facebook, target: '_blank', class: 'icon-facebook' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks @zwippie, i am trying to show both if they exist

Comment: another question sorry but it seems that has_attribute? does not like it when the field is blank (or im guessing null) as i have an example where neither facebook or twitter is populated in the DB and both links are showing

Comment: If you want to only disply the links when the attributes are non-empty, try this: `unless @team_member.twitter.blank?`

Comment: This is still not very DRY. I would put this logic in a helper (probably a parameterized one)

Comment: `has_attribute?` is asking if that column exists in the database.   If you're not sure if the column will be there (eg if @team_member can be different classes of object), and you want to test if it's there AND if it's been set, then do `if @team_member.has_attribute?(:twitter) && !@team_member.twitter.blank?`

Comment: Assertion #1 is inaccurate (-1). See, for example, http://ruby.about.com/od/control/a/The-Case-Statement.htm.

Comment: @mbratch, I stand corrected. Although I would prefer to use the if/elsif structure.

Comment: @zwippie thanks; yes, whether to use `if/else` or the expressionless `case` is a matter of choice. The latter feels a bit like the `cond` statement in Lisp. And, btw, -1 => +1. :)

Answer (score 1):

Case is used to test a value through possible set of matches:

```
<% case @team_member.whatever %>
<% when :facebook %>
  <%= link_to '', @team_member.facebook, target: '_blank', class: 'icon-facebook' %>
<% when :twitter %>
  <%= link_to '', @team_member.facebook, target: '_blank', class: 'icon-facebook' %>
<% end %>
```

What you probably looking for is `if` `elsif` statement:

```
<% if @team_member.twitter? %>
  <%= link_to '', @team_member.twitter, target: '_blank', class: 'icon-twitter' %
<% elsif @team_member.facebook? %>
  <%= link_to '', @team_member.facebook, target: '_blank', class: 'icon-facebook' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think normal `if` statements would fit your intention much better since you have different conditions for each branch.
A `case` is used for checking for different possible values for a single attribute or variable like this:

```
num_value = 5
case num_value
  when 0  # means: if num_value = 0
    doStuff()
  when 5  # means: if num_value = 5
    doOtherStuff() # this one is executed
end
```

It is usually used to just enter one of the possible branches. However, in your example you would want to show both the twitter and facebook links if the user set both, so you should use separate if statements:

```
<% if @team_member.twitter? %>
  <%= link_to '', @team_member.twitter, target: '_blank', class: 'icon-twitter' %
<% if @team_member.facebook? %>
  <%= link_to '', @team_member.facebook, target: '_blank', class: 'icon-facebook' %>
<% end %>
```

If you only want one, use `elsif` in the second check...