# case statement inside of partial stops partial from working but works outside of partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, partials, case-when

This is a very strange problem.  I have a partial that is called like this:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'layouts/logged_in/registration_form_header', f: f %>
    ....
<% end %>
```

The partial works like this:

```
Here is some text
<% puts "inside the partial %>
```

The `puts` statement shows in the console and the text displays.  If I add a case statement like this:

```
<% case @type %>
<% when 'Organization' %>
  its an organization
<% when 'Presenter' %>
      111111
      <% puts "this statement is being evaluated" %>
      <%= "inside the partial" %>
      222222
<% end #case statement for type %>
```

In the statement above, `@type` is defined as `"Presenter"` in the controller action.  I know this works because the `puts` statement is properly displaying in the console.  The only text that is outputed to the browser, however, is 222222.  The "inside the partial" string does not appear on the screen nor does the 111111.  I know that the `<% when 'Presenter' %>` code is what's being run because the puts statement works and the 222222 is appearing, but why is the rest of the content not appearing?  If I take the case statement outside of the partial and display it within the original code file, everything works as it should.

Comment: I would avoid putting all that logic in your view. But, that's beside the point...

Comment: Is this your verbatim code? I can't see any error from here, constructs like this usually work just fine (nevermind whether they are advisable or not). Can you post the actual code? Maybe you missed some "=" or "%" at strategic places. ;)

Comment: This is my actual code.  Copied and pasted directly from the partial.

Comment: Weird. Try the old divide&conquer method, delete some lines until it works and then put them back in...

Comment: Heh, take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603321/rails-switch-case-in-the-view

Comment: Doh. Goes to show that I never had a `case` in .erb's. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Overall, this is not a good way to write code. So easy to mess up things.

Define a method (e.g. `def registration_form_header(type)`) in your helper class. Put those logic into the helper method, and use the helper method to output the html you want, based on the input `@type`, then you can just do:

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb or any specific helper file
module ApplicationHelper
  def registration_form_header(type)
    ... ...
  end
end

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= registration_form_header(@type) %>
  ....
<% end %>
```